# Is it secure/possible to send two different bearer tokens in the authorization header AND the access_token?

Tags: rest, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, azure-ad-msal

I'm attempting to authenticate from service to service using a user's access credentials in OAuth 2.0.

The steps are:

1. Client authenticates against API 1
2. API 1 requests for the bearer token to access API 2
3. API 1 sends a request with API 2's bearer token in the Authorization header, and also sends the Client's bearer token in the access_token parameter.
4. API 2 creates an OBO token using the Client's token from the access_token parameter.

Is this possible/secure? I'm not sure if the HTTP auth header might overwrite the access_token or a similar issue will occur. I read in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750 that you could pass the access_token in the entity body. But seems like this has been deprecated.